# Is terra::clamp() faster than ´<- NA´ on a SpatRaster?

Tags: r, r-raster, terra

I have a **SpatRaster **and want to make sure that NA-flags (-9999 in my case) are set to NA properly.

Should I use

```
r1 <- terra::rast()
r1[r1 < 0 ] <- NA
```

or using

```
r1 <- terra::rast()
terra::clamp(r1, lower = 0)
```

if I am aiming for a memory safe/efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

`clamp` is fine. You could also do

```
s <- subst(r1, -9999, NA)
```

Or

```
s <- classify(r1, cbind(-Inf, 0, NA))
```

This is inefficient

```
r1[r1 < 0 ] <- NA
```

It is nice for quick interactive exploration, but best avoided in production code.